# getting result whole page despite expected value

Tags: php, ajax, forms, select

I've such a situation. Have select form like it is shown below and want to invoke ajax function to get result depended onchange select form, but getting whole page from ajax

here is script

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./scripts/css/default.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
<select name="s" id="s">
    <option value="one">A</option>
    <option value="two">B</option>
    <option value="three">C</option>
</select>
</form>

Hello guys ...
<div id="xe"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("s").onchange = function(){
    var h = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        h = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (h){
        h.open("POST","index.php",true);
        h.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (h.readyState==4 && h.status==200){
                document.getElementById("xe").innerHTML = h.responseText;
            }
        };
        h.send("s=" + document.getElementById("s").value);
    }
};
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['s'])){
    echo $_POST['s'];
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

any ideas ? please help , thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the $_POST lines at the top of your file and exit() afterwards:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['s'])){
    echo $_POST['s'];
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./scripts/css/default.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
<select name="s" id="s">
    <option value="one">A</option>
    <option value="two">B</option>
    <option value="three">C</option>
</select>
</form>

Hello guys ...
<div id="xe"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("s").onchange = function(){
    var h = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        h = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (h){
        h.open("POST","index.php",true);
        h.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (h.readyState==4 && h.status==200){
                document.getElementById("xe").innerHTML = h.responseText;
            }
        };
        h.send("s=" + document.getElementById("s").value);
    }
};
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've already guessed , I was missing http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); this statement :)

Comment: great! don't forget to answer your own question and mark as complete

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the `index.php` returns the whole page, having all that HTML embedded into it.

You could craft another `partial.php`, which returns the part you need to inject in your page in the browser, and point your AJAX request to it.

Comment: I just wrote this example here , in general I am doing it like you have answered ( I mean in other file writing php script) but the result is still same